# How can I update only the Gems installed in my user directory?

Tags: bash, macos, rubygems

I've been installing additional Ruby Gems on macOS (10.13.2) using the `gem install GEMNAME --user-install` command. In order to use them, I've created a **.bash_profile** and added the following line to it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin
```

The issue arises when I then try to update these Gems. I can update them all individually by specifying the name, but running `gem update` causes a file permission error due to the command trying to also update the system Gems.

Likewise, when I use the command `gem update --user-install`, this tries to install the latest versions all of the local Gems into the user directory, which seems like bad practice. Also, I want to stay away from using [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) or [rvm](https://rvm.io/) so to not over complicate things; I'm only using a handful of additional Gems.

Essentially, I'm looking for a way to run `gem update` and only target the Gems currently in the **/Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0** directory.

At present, my Gem Enviroment looks like this:

```
Ruby RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/USERNAME/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-17
  - GEM PATHS:
    - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
    - /Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
    - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
    - /usr/local/bin
    - /usr/bin
    - /bin
    - /usr/sbin
    - /sbin
    - /Users/USERNAME/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin
```

Comment: Upvoted. It looks to me as though the issue you noted with `gem upgrade --user-install` should be filed as a bug, if no-one has already done that.

Comment: Thanks, @sampablokuper. I've raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2273) over on the RubyGems GitHub reopository.

Comment: @sampablokuper You may want to bump that issue as it closed due inactivity.

Comment: @TomHale, I think you might have meant to ping dsoreilly - the person who reported the bug - instead of me.